# Auto logout user, when App in background for 5 mins, when the user resumes the app?

Tags: android

If the screen is locked (while the app is still there) or if the app has moved to background for more than 5 mins I want to logout my app. I have a BaseActivity which extends the AppCompatActivity. All other activities extends BaseActvity.
I have used the below code in BaseActivity but after 5 mins, the app opens up by itself in LoginActivity. Can you please help me with this?

**Java code below:**

```
   @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.v(TAG, "on pause called");
        timer = new Timer();
        Log.i(TAG, "Invoking logout timer");
        LogOutTimerTask logoutTimeTask = new LogOutTimerTask();
        timer.schedule(logoutTimeTask, 300000); //auto logout in 5 minutes
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.v(TAG, "on resume called");
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            Log.i(TAG, "cancel timer");
            timer = null;
        }
    }

    private class LogOutTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            //redirect user to login screen
            Constants.SESSION_ID = "";
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

I have added all possible suggestion but the timer is working even when I launch the app. A code snippet would be useful.

Comment: Do not pass Intent to LoginActivity as this will start activity

Just set you logout logic there.

Comment: use alarm manager with pending intent.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
   super.onPause();
   long LastTime= System.currentTimeMillis(); //save this time
} 



@Override
protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   long CurrentTime= System.currentTimeMillis(); //this is your current time
   //get LastTime and compare
   long difference = CurrentTime - LastTime;
   // now convert difference into minutes and start login activity
}
```

This may helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import java.util.Calendar

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTES);
```

This will give you the user's time at the moment.

You can save them in onStop() and take a look at them in onRestart()/onResume(if you destroy it). There you can apply your logic. Make some calculations so you can have information about how much time has passed and go from there.
You can save it in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) or any other way you like.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with your LogoutTimerTask class that contains the code to automatically move to login screen. Don't start an activity inside that LogoutTimerTask class. Instead, set a globally defined variable value to logout inside the run() method after 5 minutes hacve passed and when user reenters your app, I would suggest that you use that variable in onCreate to check if you have manually logged out the user or not and call appropriate activity class from there

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue using the following snippet.
Since I am using fragments after login hence, using this code only in the Activity which contains the fragments helped me.

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();


    }

    private class LogOutTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            //redirect user to login screen
            finish();
            Constants.SESSION_ID = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        timer = new Timer();
        Log.i(TAG, "Invoking logout timer");
        LogOutTimerTask logoutTimeTask = new LogOutTimerTask();
        timer.schedule(logoutTimeTask, DISCONNECT_TIMEOUT); //auto logout in 5 minutes
    }

 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            Log.i(TAG, "cancel timer");
            timer = null;
        }
}
```